# How to compare two lists in python and write the similar index values in one list and non similar values in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, string-comparison

consider two lists
a=[1,2,3], b=[1,4,5].The Code should print the similar values c=[1] and the Code should print d=[2,3,4,5] which shows different values

--completed --

Comment: @vicrobot : can u help me with ur question

Comment: where do u stuck when you try solving that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and alternative solution using [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it) and logical operators is given below:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,4,5]

print([x for x in a if x in b])
print([x for x in set(a+b) if (x in a) ^ (x in b)])
```

A solution with `set operation` has already been given by other person, so I am not repeating it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets for this

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,4,5]

c = list(set(a).intersection(b))
d = list(set(a).difference(b)) + list(set(b).difference(a))
```

`intersection` finds the common elements and `difference` finds what is different. You have to do this both ways because the `difference` operator is basically showing only the elements in the first set that aren't in the second.